# "Inspect" function (Ctrl + Shift + I) doesn't work

Tags: javascript

The "if (numero.value.length == 0)" works, but when I add a number the program doesn't work, the "Inspect" function (Ctrl + Shift + I) doesn't work and the page does not refresh.

```js
function tabuada() {
  var numero = document.getElementById('txtnum')
  var tabuada = document.getElementById("selectTab")
  if (numero.value.length == 0) {
    window.alert("Você precisa digitar um número para que a tabuada seja gerada.")
  } else {
    var num = Number(numero.value)
    tabuada.innerHTML = ""
    for (c = 0; c = 10; c++) {
      var item = document.createElement('option')
      item.text = `${num} * ${c} = ${c * num}`
      tabuada.appendChild(item)
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <p>
      Escolha um número: <input type="number" name="num" id="txtnum">
      <input type="button" value="Gerar Tabuada" onclick="tabuada()">
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <select name="tabuada" id="selectTab" size="10"></select>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: The `F12` key can also be used to open the dev tools.

Comment: This doesn't work either

Comment: Your for loop is incorrect ```for (c = 0; c = 10; c++) {``` replace this with 
```for (c = 0; c <= 10; c++) {```

Answer (score 0):

You had to look more on your code:

- Every opnening tag needs a closing one. /BODY and /HTML was missing.
- Every line in Javascript needs a `;` at the end.
- The condition of your for-loop was wrong. You made an allocation `c = 10` (which is allways true, so you have an infinite loop). If you want to compare something on equal use `===` or `==`. But you had to compare for  `c < 10`. The loop will as long iterate as your condition is true so smaller than is the choice.
- Your function needs a closing `}`.

```js
     function tabuada() {
        var numero = document.getElementById('txtnum');
        var tabuada = document.getElementById("selectTab");
        if (numero.value.length == 0) {
            window.alert("Você precisa digitar um número para que a tabuada seja gerada.");
        } else {       
            var num = Number(numero.value);
            tabuada.innerHTML = "";
            for (c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
                var item = document.createElement('option');
                item.text =  `${num} * ${c} = ${c * num}`;
                tabuada.appendChild(item);
            }
         }
     }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tabuada</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_estiloEx16.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Tabuada</h1>
    </header>
    <section>
      <div>
        <p>
          Escolha um número: <input type="number" name="num" id="txtnum"> 
          <input type="button" value="Gerar Tabuada" onclick="tabuada()">
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <select name="tabuada" id="selectTab" size="10"></select>
      </div>
    </section>
    <footer>
      <p>&copy; Curso em vídeo</p>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```